# Accessing object properties between classes in kivy

Tags: sqlite, kivy, python-3.6

This bit of Code here creates a scrollview of buttons to allow me select from a list of different "tickets"

```
    SearchResultButton(Button(text=str(Datarray2[i]),id=str(Datarray2[i]),on_press=self.Pressbtn ))
self.ids.SearchResult.add_widget(SearchResultButton)
```

From there it opens this function, which should set a variable (In this case "UpdateTicketNum") which will be used in another function to set the label text in another screen.

```
def Pressbtn(self, SearchResultButton):
    global UpdateTicket
    UpdateTicket = OPENTicket
    woo = SearchResultButton.text
    print(SearchResultButton.text)
    wow = [blank.strip() for blank in woo.split(',')]
    print("\n\n\n\n")
    global UpdateTicketNum
    UpdateTicketNum = (wow[0])

    self.manager.get_screen('UpdateTicket').UpdateOpen()
```

At this point it opens up the sqlite DB and double checks that the TicketNumber is valid. The issue comes in when trying to access the label inside the kv build

```
def UpdateOpen(self):
    print("TESTSETST")
    conn = sqlite3.connect('TicketData.db', timeout=10)
    UD = conn.cursor()


    UD.execute('SELECT TicketNumber FROM TicketData WHERE TicketNumber = ?',(UpdateTicketNum,))
    tips = UD.fetchone()
    print(tips[0])
    tipsy = tips[0]

    UpdatedLabelTexT = tipsy
    sm.current=('UpdateTicket')
    UpdateTicket.ids.UpdateLabels['text']=(UpdatedLabelTexT)
```

The UpdateTicket.ids.UpdateLabels['text']=UpdatedLabelText] field always claims to be a property of the scrollview buttons even though I am initializing it inside another class, and with different parameters. apologies if this question is poorly formatted. but 3 days of dying trying to figure this out and I snapped.

Here is the bit in KV

```
<UpdateTicket>
name: 'UpdateTicket'
on_enter:
    root.UpdateOpen()

orientation: "vertical"
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .0, .6, 1, 1
        Rectangle:  
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "lights.jpg"
Label:
    id: UpdateLabels
    text: "filler"
    multiline: False
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (root.width/5,root.height/20)
    pos_hint:{'center_x': .5,'center_y': .5 }
```

and how I initialize the screen

```
sm.add_widget(UpdateTicket(name='UpdateTicket'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that worked for me. when first initializing the app
class SampleApp(App)
    return sm(to build the application)

I needed to replace that return SM with

```
    global root
    return sm

    root = ScreenManager()
    return root
```

And that appeared to fix my issue. thanks for reading